# How to replace double quotes within a string with apostrophe (not the outer double quotes specifying it's a string)

Tags: python, linux, bash, sed

I have pipe delimited .txt files in Linux that contain strings within double quotes.

Some of the strings will have a double quote instead of an apostrophoe.

e.g. I"m a string.

This will be represented in the file within the pipes as "I"m a string"

I need to replace "I"m a string" with "I'm a string".

How can I do that with sed or using Python/Jupyter?

Examples

```
"String"|"I"m not a valid string"|"I'm a valid string"
```

Based on the data requirements I don't need to worry about things like:

1. Pipe within the double quotes e.g. "Str|Srt"|"Str"
2. Mix of double and single quotes e.t. "Str'|'Str"

Comment: Not `"I""m a string"`? Doubling up the quotes is the usual way to escape them in CSV-like formats.

Comment: @Shawn - the example I'm using is from an external file I've used. so the format I receive data in is "word"|"I"m another word"|"Something else". In this case I'm trying to fix the "I"m another word" to "I'm another word". Were you suggesting to replace " with "" and it will read it fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed "s/\"/'/g; s/'|'/\"|\"/g; s/^'/\"/; s/'$/\"/" file
"String"|"I'm not a valid string"|"I'm a valid string"
```

Answer (score 3):

This `sed` should work

```
sed -E "s/([A-Za-z0-9])\"([^|].*)/\1\'\2/g" input_file
```

With grouping in `sed`, you can exclude the invalid quote `"` from the match and replace it when reinstating the groups.

**Output**

```
"I'm a string"
```

Comment: That's exactly the output I want but haven't managed to make it work. I'll look at it again and update the thread. thank you.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU or BSD sed for `-E`. If you make it `-r` then it'll only work in older versions of GNU sed, not BSD. I suspect it'll fail if any of the quoted strings contain anything that's not a number though, e.g. `"I am 7"th in line"`, or cases with multiple `"`s in the string.

Comment: It's not just integers though, it could be punctuation or white space too. Your text says you want to excluded the `"` so just write/use the regexp for that, `[^"]` instead of trying to write a regexp that includes all chars that aren't a `"` if that's the intent.

Comment: @EdMorton Noted :) I work with the data provided. If the OP has further requirements or more conditional parameters, it should be presented so there is usable data to work with. I have edited taking your consideration into account.

Comment: Understood but when a question is about a string, you should assume that string can contain any characters except the ones the OP tells you it can't contain rather than assuming it can only contain the subset of characters used in an example since the OP typically can't create an example showing [all combinations of] all possible characters.

Answer (score 2):

I might be tempted to use perl

```sh
$ cat file.txt
"first"|"second"|"I"m a string"|"fourth"

$ perl -lne '
  print join "|",              # join, clearly
    map {"\"" . $_ . "\""}     # re-add outer quotes
    map {s/"/\047/g; $_}       # replace inner quotes
    map {s/^"|"$//g; $_}       # remove leading/trailing quotes
    split /[|]/                # split the input on pipes
' file.txt
"first"|"second"|"I'm a string"|"fourth"
```

Although, as Shawn comments, replacing inner quotes with doubled double quotes gives you valid CSV.

```perl
    map {s/"/""/g; $_}       # replace inner quotes
```

Comment: I don't know Perl, so added a clarification in the description to ask if this can be done using Bash (sed) or in Python/Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape " and ' when using sed. The syntax for the sed command is:
"s/old_pattern/new_pattern/g", where "g" stands for global matching.
The solution you need is:

```
sed -i "s/\"/\'/g" file.txt
```

Comment: This replaces all double quotes with single, doesn't work

Comment: You don't need to escape `'`, it's already literal.